# pygraphviz ValueError: Program dot not found in path

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

the problem is:
I am on Windows7 and I've installed pygraphviz library and Graphviz application(Graphviz application is in "C:\Program Files"). When I run my program on python I have the following message:

```
g.draw(filename,prog='dot')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1418, in draw
    data=self._run_prog(prog,args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1248, in _run_prog
    runprog=self._get_prog(prog)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1236, in _get_prog
    raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path."%prog) 
ValueError: Program dot not found in path.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @George Stocker, I do not think this is a "real" duplicate because the other post only deals with Unix systems. On Windows, it is a whole different story.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the directory with graphviz binaries to `PATH`.

Comment: I just done it but nothing happened =(

Comment: @nonameg are you sure you are using the updated environment?

Comment: what's the updated environment?

Comment: @nonameg if you only changed the environment variable settings in the system settings, you need to relogin for them to take effect.

Comment: @wRAR or open a new command prompt if you're doing it from the command line.

Comment: what should be the updated path variable?