# pygraphviz ValueError: Program dot not found in path (python)

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am having problem with pygraphviz on win7(64). I installed Graphviz and then pygraphviz. When I try to compile my code

```
G=pgv.AGraph()
d={'1': {'2': None}, '2': {'1': None, '3': None}, '3': {'2': None}}
A=pgv.AGraph(d)
G.add_node(1, color='red')
G.add_edge('b','c',color='blue')
G.layout(prog='dot') 
G.draw('file.png')
```

I get this error

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1738, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "D:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1355, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\Users\SUUSER\workspace\ThreadGraph\parseText.py", line 17, in <module>
    G.layout(prog='dot') 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1305, in layout
    data=self._run_prog(prog,' '.join([args,"-T",fmt]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1251, in _run_prog
    runprog=r'"%s"'%self._get_prog(prog)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1239, in _get_prog
    raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path."%prog)
ValueError: Program dot not found in path.
```

Dont tell me it is a duplicate. I looked all answers.

> [pygraphviz ValueError: Program dot not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path?rq=1)
>
> [(Python) ValueError: Program dot not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014465/pygraphviz-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path?rq=1)
>
> [PyGraphViz agraph.layout() throws I0 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513085/pygraphviz-agraph-layout-throws-i0-error)

Comment: Can you run graphviz executables from outside Python? Such as `dot`, for example?

Comment: @Bach from bin directory right? When I click on dot.exe, just command line comes out. Nothing else happens.

Answer (score 1):

You may get this problem even if you have PyGraphviz installed, if the PyGraphviz bin directory has not been added to the path. I had this problem on windows (after installing PyGraphviz with .msi).

To resolve, add the bin directory (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin) to the PATH system variable, e.g. on Win7:

System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System Varibales -> PATH -> Edit...

Comment: "sudo apt install graphviz" on some flavours of linux

Answer (score 1):

If you have Anaconda installed the simplest way to go about this is run the following from CMD:

```
conda install graphviz
```

you might also need the following:

```
conda install pydot-ng
```