# How to enable path on user environment in eclipse-PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, path, pydev

If any ideas how to enable PyDev(eclipse) enables path or symbolic link to call foreign program(programs in /usr/local/bin/) in MacOS(/Linux), please tell me.

---

I want to use graphviz via pygraphviz on PyDev in eclipse. However, error message occurred such as "ValueError: Program dot not found in path." or "ValueError: No prog dot in path."

I guessed the below similar problems of which the cause may be IDE(e.g. PyDev) not to enable paths to call foreign command, for example, /usr/local/bin/dot.

The reason is I could perform graphviz on eclipse in below environment just as expected.

- Sample code I want to perform

  ```
   import pygraphviz
   G=pygraphviz.AGraph()
   G.add_node('a')
   G.add_edge('b','c')
   G.layout()
   G.draw('sample01.png')
  ```
- Successed cases

  - In terminal.app, the upper sample code could be perform just as expected. Off course, the python was same used in my eclipe.
  - The same eclipse which run in the upper terminal.app by command "open ~/Application/Eclipse.app" can be performed the upper sample code just as expected. Off course, in the terminal.app the upper code can be performed.
- My environment.

  - MacBookPro MacOS(10.10:yosemite)
  - Eclipse Luna (Installed via homebrew-cask)
  - PyDev 4.0
  - Python 3.4 (installed by conda)
  - PyGraphviz 1.3rc2 (built source codes gotten from GitHub)
  - Graphviz 2.38.0 (Installed via homebrew)
- Similar question

  - [pygraphviz ValueError: Program dot not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014465/pygraphviz-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path)
  - [(Python) ValueError: Program dot not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path)
  - [pygraphviz ValueError: Program dot not found in path (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324459/pygraphviz-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path-python)

Comment: Refer to my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/77921791#77921791 for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program from the terminal it can find the `graphviz` tool because its location is included in the `PATH` environment variable. This environment variable is defined in your `~/.bash_profile`, which is executed if you log in at the terminal. Eclipse doesn't use this file and therefore doesn't know the location of `graphviz`.

So your problems boils down to *"how to set an environment variable OS-X"*. If you phrase it like this, Google will return a lot more results since many people have encountered the same issue. Unfortunately the solution depends on your version of OS-X so I cannot give you a short answer here. Besides, other people have written far better answers than I can. I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308) may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the below method which is based on your suggestion.

**1. Answer Method**

Add the system path of Python with the below code.

`os.environ['PATH']` indicates an operator of the system path. The below code added a path `/usr/local/bin` where there is a symbolic link file to the `graphviz cui` program to a based path `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:'`

You can find out your system base path using the below code.

```
    import os
    os.environ['PATH']='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'

    import os
    print(os.environ.get('PATH'))
```

**2. Tried Method** (this could not solve)

To add system path in /etc/path.d/

I added a file "Eclipse" where there described `/usr/local/bin` to `/etc/path.d/`.
But this method did not solve the problem.